# How to reshape an Image in pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, dataset, pytorch

I have an image of shape `(32, 3, 32, 32)`. I know it's of the form `(batch_size, Channel, Height, Width)`.

Q. How do I convert it to be `(32, 32, 32)` overriding the `Channel`?

Comment: What do you mean by "overriding the Channel"? If you have two numbers, how do you want to convert them to just one number? Pick the largest? Take the mean value? Or?

Comment: I have converted the image to greyscale, I expected to get output of `32, 32, 32` rather i got `32, 1, 32, 32`

Comment: Then just squeeze the output (i.e. remove the dimension of size 1), using `torch.squeeze`.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to grayscale you could do this:

`image.mean(dim=1)`